# How to merge two array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have problem when try to merge two array in PHP.For example:

```
$array1 = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [count] => 6.5
        )
)
```

and array two follow:

```
 $array2 = Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => abc
                [user_id] => 1
            ),
        [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => xyz
            [user_id] => 2
        ),
    )
```

I want to merge two array above follow:

```
$array3 = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => abc
            [user_id] => 1
            [count] => 6.5
        ),
    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => xyz
        [user_id] => 2
        [count] => 0 //set default = 0 if not exist count
    ),
)
```

So what can I will do, anyone?

Comment: Where do you get the data from? A database?

Comment: yep, I get data from database.Output is something like my post

Comment: What do the database queries look like? You should join data directly in the database.

Comment: I'm using laravel, so my queries look like :
 `$users = DB::table('users')
            ->select('name','user_id')
            ->get();`

     and  `$speech = DB::table('users')
            ->select('user_id', DB::raw('AVG(point) as count'))
            ->leftJoin('evalute','users.user_id','=','evalute.user_id')
            ->where('id_evaluate' ,'=', $id_evaluate)
            ->get();`

Comment: Which table does `point` come from? Also, why do you make two queries on the same table? Surely you should only be doing one query, yes?

Comment: join data directly in the database is impossible, data into two table `point` come from table `evaluate` not `users`.In addition, $users has many row than $speech

Comment: Joining data is what databases **do**. Why on earth would it be impossible?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this data is coming from a database then chances are the easiest way to achieve the result is using a join on your database query.

However - here's how you can do it with PHP:

Firstly you want to remap `$array1` to user the user ID as its key. This way you avoid needing to nest a loop inside a loop to find the count, and can reference it immediately via the user ID which exists in both arrays:

```
// Re-map keys for array 1 so you don't have to loop it every time
$temp = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $values) {
    $temp[$values->user_id] = $values;
}
$array1 = $temp
```

[Here's an example](https://eval.in/527187) of what `$array1` looks like after you've done this.

Next, construct your `$array3` based on `$array2` with the added `count` from `$array1` if it exists, otherwise assign zero by default:

```
// Construct your output array
$array3 = array();    
foreach ($array2 as $values) {
    $values->count = array_key_exists($values->user_id, $array1)
        ? $array1[$values->user_id]->count
        : 0;
    $array3[] = $values;
}
```

Your output from `$array3` will then look [like this](https://eval.in/527186).